# How to Fix Polygon Stretching Error in React Leaflet Map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geospatial, react-leaflet

I am working on a project where I am using the react-leaflet package to display a series of polygons on a map, based on data fetched from an external API. I am experiencing an issue where some polygons appear to be stretching incorrectly on the map. I suspect this may be due to the longitudinal values being very close to 0° and 360° but I am not entirely sure.

the data contains coordinates of polygons on Mars represented by four pairs of latitude and longitude points (C1, C2, C3, C4). Each pair contains a latitude and longitude coordinate.

Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-polygon-forked-g60cs9) to my project on CodeSandbox where you can see the current state of my code and the issue live.

I greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions you may be able to provide. Thank you!

[image: Map with the strechted polygons but also with working polygons]